# Xcode 7.2 - UIDatePicker not showing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uidatepicker, invisible

i have a problem with a UIDatePicker since it doesn't appear on the view in my app.

This is the code i have for the UIDatePicker:

```
self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];

self.datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(10,170, self.view.window.frame.size.width, 200);`
NSDate *maxDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:94608000 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];`
self.datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate;
self.datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[self.view addSubview:self.datePicker];
```

I tested to see if the UIDatePicker was nil but turns out it wasn't, it's like the view is loaded but just invisible i even had it log a date in the console.

I have been trying to find a solution for a long time now, but without success.
Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

**Extra Info:**
I have deleted the Framework Search Paths in my MyAppTests targets in order to make a warning go away after an update in Xcode, this was before i noticed the UIDatePicker. I don't know if that could have affected it.

EDIT: I did also update to recommended settings on my app / project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CGRectMake` you have an error when you set the width of frame. `self.view.window.frame.size.width` retun 0. You need to set `self.view.frame.size.width`. I Hope it work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Check code again

**Code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];

    picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);
    picker.minimumDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
    picker.maximumDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:10];
    picker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    [self.view addSubview:picker];
}
```